# Hosting providers for .Net 4 / MVC 3 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, .net-4.0, hosting

I’ve developed an application over **.Net 4 / MVC 3**. And now I want to host, this is my first ever hosting experience so I'm confused and seriously need help.

It’s not so complex application basically serving as a community image sharing website.
Now I'm looking for a hosting service for it, I don’t know much about it but what I’ve learnt I think I need following in it.

- Host provided using **IIS 7** (that’s fully supports **.NET4/MVC3** so I could ideally use MVC routing functionalities totally, without having the headache of adding extensions in route and support functionalities (File MIME Types, Custom Error Pages etc.)
- As it’s a community website, so it should remain available 24/7 like good server performance and availability, so users don’t get bugged by server not available and alike errors.
- Domain registering/hosting functionality, Security
- SQL Server support, an easy control panel (I think Cpanel?)
- Dedicated IP address for my website (for SSL and better SEO)
- Ideally unlimited bandwidth/space packages (because it image sharing so it can be increasing in both parameters)
- And of rouse as it’s not actually a commercial product so be compact in price.

I know I’ve put up a lot of points up, but I’ve also searched through other threads and other forums and found out these as recommended options, any words over their performance and support:

[Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/asp_net_web_hosting) | [Seekdotnet](http://www.seekdotnet.com/asp.net-web-hosting/)

Comment: I use Arvixe due to needing full-trust. But AFAIK, you can use probably any hosting provider for MVC3, bar old IIS.

Comment: Using [SmarterASP](http://www.SmarterASP.NET/index?r=100651500) from 4+ years... no issues till now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some you can use. Depending on the price you want to pay.
I have godd experiences with GoDaddy and DiscoutASP (both offers what you need, depending on what you want to pay).

But there are so many hosters. Its not only the features and price that counts, it is also the location of the servers .

#### Companies

- [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/)
- [DiscountASP](http://discountasp.net/)
- [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/asp_net_web_hosting)
- [Seekdotnet](http://www.seekdotnet.com/asp.net-web-hosting/)
- [WinHost](http://www.winhost.com/)
- [Peer Hosting Stackoverflow Offer](http://www.peer1.com/stackoverflow)

#### Hosting Lists / Directories

- [Windows Web Hosting Gallery](http://www.asp.net/hosting/home)
- [Best ASP.NET Hosting](http://www.findbestwebhosting.com/Top10hostingcompanies.aspx/Windows-Web-Hosting/1)
- [Best Windows Hosting](http://www.windowshostingasp.net/Top_Best_ASP_NET_Hosting_Providers.aspx)

Comment: I moved everything to http://www.smarterasp.net/ - support service is rocks.

Answer (score 5):

**Just my experience**

One of my website is hosted on [Godaddy](http://godaddy.com). The domain and hosting was ordered on 22 december 2011. To be honest, they may be cheap and enticing at first, but their services aren't too great to talk about. My site is hosted on Asia-Pacific servers so I am talking about those only. The one's in US might have good standard so I can't comment. Actually they have too many customers so it's basically boils down to very tedious task to manage all of those. But, even if we say this, that's what we pay them for.

[DiscountAsp](http://discountasp.net) is a slight bit expensive and it's good too. No current experience, but they were great when I tried them in 2009 so I suppose they might have only improved. But, do consider the reviews from real users for this hosting provider.

[Cytanium](http://www.cytanium.com) is another hosting provider. My friend has a website hosted on it and if his views can be taken, it's a very recommended windows hosting provier. If your requirements aren't that big, you will find it cheap.

**Additional Info**

You haven't asked for deployment guidance, but I am listing a decent article for getting things up and running with few insights into this important aspect of web development : [Deployment to a Hosting Provider](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-introduction-1-of-12)

Answer (score 4):

[Winhost](http://www.winhost.com/) is a good option, and I believe it has everything you need. I am currently using it to host a .NET4/MVC3 website.